# InstallShield 2012 LE yields "6417 Internal build error" when building

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-2012, installshield-le

I just updated from Visual Studio 2010 and InstallShield 2011 LE.  VS would build my projects, and the installers generated by IS would build and work as expected.

After updating to Visual Studio 2012 and InstallShield 2012 LE, when building the SingleImage configuration I'm getting...

> Error 6 -6103: Could not find file "C:\dev\MySolution\MyProject\obj\x86\Release\MyProject.exe" ISEXP : error : -6103: Could not find file "C:\dev\MySolution\MyProject\obj\x86\Release\MyProject.exe"
>
> Error 10 -6271: File C:\dev\MySolution\MyProject\obj\x86\Release\MyProject.exe not found. An error occurred building the MsiFileHash table record for this file. Verify that the file exists in the specified location. ISEXP : error : -6271: File C:\dev\MySolution\MyProject\obj\x86\Release\MyProject.exe not found. An error occurred building the MsiFileHash table record for this file. Verify that the file exists in the specified location.
>
> Error 11 -6417: Internal build error ISEXP : error : -6417: Internal build error

I have verified that the file exists in the specified location.  I'm not sure where to go from here, or even what question I should be asking.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was project dependencies!  For some reason, after the update to VS2012 and IS2012, my IS projects no longer depended on the projects they required.  So sometimes the required projects would already be built from an earlier compilation, sometimes not.

The fix was just right clicking the solution, opening the Project Dependencies dialog, and checking the right boxes.